# Is there a way to make a weighted table by two groups (one group displayed at columns and the other at rows)?

Tags: survey, gtsummary

I want to make a weighted table of a I601Z2 variable, both by DOMINIO and P601A. I'm aware that I can do this with a stratified table, but that option won't allow me to put one of these two group variables in the rows. I want to have the DOMINIO variable in columns and P601A in rows. The cells would include the mean (or sum, or SD, etc.) of I601Z2 which must be calculated using another variable called FACTOR07, which is the weight for each case in the dataset.

You can find those variables in this dataset.

```
load(url("https://github.com/cesarpoggi/PRUEBA/blob/main/PRUEBA_STACKOVERFLOW.rda?raw=true"))
```

I'd be very thankfull if someone can help me with this. Here is an example of what I need, hopefully this will make it clearer.

[image]

Comment: please update your post with a mock-up of a table you'd like to see in the end.

Comment: @DanielD.Sjoberg I just updated it! I added a picture of what I'd to see at the end. Also added some extra info in the description. Hopefully, you can help me.

Comment: The gtsummary package exports a function called `tbl_continuous()` that produces tables like this for unweighted data only unfortunately.